# PlayonLinux cannot install MS office 2010 spanish in Lubuntu 14.04.1 32 bit, winbind missing

Tags: lubuntu, samba, playonlinux

When I tried to install MS Office Professional Plus 2010 in spanish (only Word, Excel and PowerPoint) through PlayonLinux, an error message appears saying

> winbind is not installed

If I try to install samba (there are two packages to choose, I tried both of them) through Lubuntu Software center to get winbind, it shows another error message:

> cannot resolve dependencies. Samba was not installed

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem myself:

1. Perform a clean installation of Lubuntu.
2. Update the system through the System Updater (in System Tools). If you do this in a Live USB with persistence created on Windows with a FAT32 file system, as I did, The maximum space allowed for new software/files/folders is 4GB, so, after the system update you'll find that there is no space enough to install MS Office. In this case you must perform a partial system update: check mark only samba/winbind/phyton related items, leave the others unmarked and perform the update.
3. Install PlayonLinux from Lubuntu Software Center
4. Install MS Office 2010. It will also download some missing packages from the internet. If there are any error messages/warnings, don't worry, continue the install.
5. Reboot and enjoy.

I cannot yet activate all the complements in Excel (only Analysis Tools, but Analysis Tools - VBA, Euro Tools and Solver cannot be activated) but otherwise it's working.